# Google Spreadsheet Custom Menu Returned Script Function Not Found

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to add a custom menu to the google spreadsheet editor's interface to activate a script by Tony Hirst to pull calendar events into the spreadsheet.

By when I click on the custom menu option, it returned "script function not found: GetCalendar()"

I have tried to make modifications and read the google documentation but am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

```
/**
* A custom function that gets the calendar events by calendar ID.
*/
function GetCalendar() {
// get the spreadsheet object
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// set the second sheet as active
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[1]);
// fetch this sheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

//http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendar.html#getEvents
// The code below will retrieve events between 2 dates for the user's default calendar and
// display the events the current spreadsheet
var calId = "SpecificCalendarID";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("June 15, 2015"), new Date("March 20, 2080"));
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
//http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendarevent.html
var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime()]];
var row=i+2;
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,3);
range.setValues(details);
  }
}

/**
* A function that runs when the spreadsheet is open, used to add a
* custom menu to the spreadsheet.
*/
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var menuItems = ui.createMenu ('Custom Menu');
menuItems.addItem ('Get Events','GetCalendar()');
menuItems.addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis from `GetCalendar()`

Should be:

```
menuItems.addItem ('Get Events','GetCalendar');
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to this and hope to ask less of such silly questions in future.

Comment: Please mark as correct answer.  I've made the same mistake plenty of times.  Take some time to read the troubleshooting documentation at the following link.  [Google Documentation - Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)